# Why does the Rails guide suggest using the scoped method on associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) state that a scope can be called on an association. But then [further on](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes), it states that the `scoped` method, which returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, "may come in handy...on associations". If a scope can be called on an association, what additional functionality does `scoped` provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scoped`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped) returns an *anonymous* scope. From the API docs:

> Anonymous scopes tend to be useful when procedurally generating complex queries, where passing intermediate values (scopes) around as first-class objects is convenient.

Here's the example:

```
posts = Post.scoped
posts.size # Fires "select count(*) from  posts" and returns the count
posts.each {|p| puts p.name } # Fires "select * from posts" and loads post objects

fruits = Fruit.scoped
fruits = fruits.where(:color => 'red') if options[:red_only]
fruits = fruits.limit(10) if limited?
```